# Single Device Push Notifications (FCM Registration Token) not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using react-native-firebase with firebase-messaging to implement push notifications.

While I can send push notifications to everyone, I'm unable to send them to individuals. To my knowledge, all I need is the FCM Registration Token which I retrieve [by following the documentation](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/messaging/device-token.md)

```
firebase.messaging().getToken()
  .then(fcmToken => {
    if (fcmToken) {
      console.log("fcm token", fcmToken);
    } else {
      console.log("fcm token", "null");
    } 
  });
```

The token I receive is a plausible token, but when I copy that token from the logs into the firebase console and try to send it to a single device, nothing is received. (If I push to a user segment, it's received by all devices with the app installed).

As I can not test for iOS, this might or might not also be a problem on iOS.

In my build.gradle file, the firebase relevant libraries are included like so:

```
compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
    transitive = false
}

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0"
```

In the MainApplication.java file I add them to the list of ReactPackages.

```
new RNGoogleSigninPackage(),
new RNFirebasePackage(),
new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
new RNFirebaseAuthPackage()
```

My AndroidManifest does not have any Firebase relevant changes as I discovered that push notifications were working even without them. (While trying to implement push notifications I noticed that all phones were receiving them except the one I was actively working on - so I rolled back the code.)

edit: I managed to receive one single device notification. Without any changes, it was suddenly working exactly once. Now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Something else must be going on. If you are able to send messages to all users and you receive those, you should be able to send to a single device by using the FCM token. Keep in mind that in some situations the token might not be delivered - that's why you have an expire time for them. If they are not delivered in that time the system won't try to send them anymore.

Comment: Have you tried using high priority and sending a notification only message